# Convert Gradle Project To Maven (Mini2Dx)

Tags: java, gradle, build-tools, mini2dx

Is there a way to convert a gradle project fully into maven?
The only things I found where guides to produce a pom file, which basically only conatins dependencies but no "building steps".

*Background:
I built a small java game using command line outputs to display the game output.
As next step I want to build a graphical diaplay of the game. For this purpose I chose mini2Dx.
The Problem is: mini2Dx is using a setup-tool to setup new Projects. This setup Tool generates a gradle project. Most questions about setting up a new game lead to using this tool, so there is not much help for setting up the project manually.
My current project containing all the logic is a maven project and I only know maven. So I would prefer staying with maven.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately for you, no.

mini2Dx uses its own [gradle plugins](https://github.com/mini2Dx/parcl) to build the game, so you either have to go with gradle, or to use a different framework.